# Using MongoDB for storing and retrieving files

Tags: mongodb, ftp, nosql

Our system generates a lot of large XML files with the help of a background job. These are then processed by another background job to generate PDF. As of now we were storing everything over FTP with the paths being stored in a RDBMS. The user processes can then access the corresponding files (if they exist) and display.

During our team discussions for enhancing the system, a suggestion came up of storing these XMLs and PDFs over a NoSQL database. The arguments in support of NoSQL are:(we are not experts in NoSQL)

- It would help us manage the updation and deletion of files better
- The files can be easily backed up or replicated to multiple servers
- Files should be faster to access than conventional FTP

Though we do not need any content filtering except for a identifier for file, I was wondering if this is a viable solution for replacing FTP and if so is MongoDB a good NoSQL database for this task.

Comment: Why all the close votes ?

Comment: I mean, I get that this isn't what a SO question should look like, but I had the same question and I found it (and the answer) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

having been there done that, I can say yes it is a good solution, all 3 of the arguments mentioned really stand, especially [if your  file size is <16Mbytes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) , if not you have to use [gridfs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) which complicates things a little but not much.

Also if file size is small and you got enough memory you can use a [covered query](http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/chapter4/) which can get you retrieval speeds comparable to [redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317732/why-use-redis-instead-of-mongodb-for-caching)

Comment: Is MongoDB the right choice for an enterprise level deployment ?

Comment: IMO yes, but then again this kind of question can only get a highly biased objective answer