# How to use MongoDb In-Memory as Spring Cache Provider

Tags: spring, mongodb, caching, redis

Does anyone have experience with using a MongoDb in-memory database as cache with Spring Framework caching system ?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/cache.html

I've been searching quite a lot, but still haven't found any real example on this and I'm kinda wondering why.

I know Redis is a popular solution, but MongoDb seemed like a good alternative.

Comment: not sure if you are asking [Why Use Redis instead of MongoDb for Caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317732/why-use-redis-instead-of-mongodb-for-caching) or you want [plug a different back-end cache in spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/cache/plug.html). Loosk like someone created a [spring cache mongo lib](https://github.com/arhs/spring-cache-mongodb) but the last commit was 
on Mar 6, 2018.